Unable to match custom method REST routes to ruby on rails
I am new to ruby-on-rails and having a hard time trying to get routes to match for my API service.
I designed my custom routes for resources following the Google AIP-136.
For example, for the following routes

/books/{book_id}:doSomething
/books/{book_id}:doSomeOtherThing

In config/routes.rb, I expected the following to work -
post '/books/:id/\:doSomething', to: 'books#do_something_handler'
post '/books/:id/\:doSomeOtherThing', to: 'books#do_some_other_thing_handler'

But this does not work.
I get a ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/books/1234:doSomething"):
I tried some other things as well, but did not get a very satisfactory result.
Could someone help me out with how to do this properly.
Using -

Rails 7.1.3.4
ruby 3.3.4


Do you really need it? "Custom methods should only be used for functionality that can not be easily expressed via standard methods; prefer standard methods if possible, due to their consistent semantics.". I would as far as possible try to stick to just using Rails standard CRUD routes. It's also questionable why you would want to apply a set of guideline for Google's own API's to your own. They are as usual pretty freaking wierd.

Hi @max, yes your right, it's of course preferred to have standard methods over custom ones. I just have a very specific requirement. Also, personally, I think Google AIP provides a well-defined set of guidelines for API design. However when it comes to API designs I don't think there's any last words. Most important things is to have all parties agree to it.

Using constraints:
# POST /books/1:doSomething
post "/books/:id::custom_method", 
  to: "books#do_something_handler",
  constraint: {custom_method: "doSomething"}

# POST /books/1:doSomethingElse
post "/books/:id::custom_method",
  to: "books#do_something_else",
  constraints: {custom_method: "doSomethingElse"}

Using rails' action param, in this case custom method would need to match the action name:
# POST /books/1:doSomething
# routes to `doSomething` controller action
post "/books/:id::action", controller: :books


To test:
<%= form_with url: "books/1:doSomething" do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= form_with url: "books/1:doSomethingElse" do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

route with constraints:
Started POST "/books/1:doSomething" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-07-26 15:36:50 -0400
Processing by BooksController#do_something as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Save ", "id"=>"1", "custom_method"=>"doSomething"}
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms | Allocations: 1332)


Started POST "/books/1:doSomethingElse" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-07-26 15:36:52 -0400
Processing by BooksController#do_something_else as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Save ", "id"=>"1", "custom_method"=>"doSomethingElse"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms | Allocations: 892)

route with action param:
Started POST "/books/1:doSomething" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-07-26 15:11:22 -0400
Processing by BooksController#doSomething as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Save ", "id"=>"1"}
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms | Allocations: 1008)


I still get the same error with these changes

@SauravDas i've added my test. seems to work in both cases.

Hi @Alex, when I add both the routes for doSomething and doSomeOtherThing then it doesn't go to two different handlers anymore

Hey @Alex, yes, you're right. I had mistakenly written constraint without the s and rails did not complain at all, but just kept routing me wrong. Thanks.
Also saw that this works as well - '/books/:id::custom_method' without escaping the :. Accepting the answer.
